# Bridge OpenVPN to PPTP

Tags: openvpn, pptp

I want a Debian server to connect to an OpenVPN server and then provide the network that is shared using the OpenVPN server (my home network) using PPTP (host a PPTP server that provides access to my home network which has an OpenVPN server in it). How can I do this?

I know PPTP is not secure. There are reasons I have to use this for though.

It is sadly not possible to directly host the PPTP server in the home network as the default port for it is somehow already used by my router and Windows only accepts PPTP servers on the default port.

Comment: You have used the term "bridge" - this may be possible, but will be way harder then routing.  Did you specifically require bridging or simply wanting to facilitate access between PPTP clients and OpenVPN clients? Also, where is the PPTP host, and what subnets are involved ?

Comment: The goal is to provide PPTP clients with access to the network of the OpenVPN server. @davidgo